# Google Docs Apps Script Find and Replace with Italics

Tags: google-apps-script, replace, google-docs, italics

Is there a code for google apps script that finds and replaces a specific word with the italic version in a document?

Answer (score 2):

Try this -

Sample text:

> but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It
>
> but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It
>
> but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It

The following code with change the word 'unchanged' to *Italics* -

```
function myFunction() {
  var wordToReplace = 'unchanged';
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  toIta(wordToReplace, body);
}

function toIta(wordToReplace, body) {
  var findTextElm = body.findText(wordToReplace);
  while (findTextElm != null) {
    var text = findTextElm.getElement().asText();
    var start = findTextElm.getStartOffset();
    var end = findTextElm.getEndOffsetInclusive();
    text.setItalic(start, end, true);
    findTextElm = body.findText(wordToReplace, findTextElm);
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.